# Importing CreateJS into Angular 6 Application

Tags: angular, typescript, createjs

I am trying to use CreateJS in my Angular application. I have installed both the typing and createjs NPM packages. I have put `/// <reference types="@types/createjs" />` at the top of my file. The app compiles, but in the web browser it gives me the error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: createjs is not defined

How can I define 'createjs'? My typescript code is below. Thank you.

```
/// <reference types="@types/createjs" /> 
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'timeline-creator',
  template: '<canvas width="1000" height="500"id="demoCanvas"></canvas>'
})
export class TimelineCreatorComponent implements AfterViewInit {

 ngAfterViewInit (){


  var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas")
  var circle = new createjs.Shape();
  circle.graphics.beginFill("DeepSkyBlue").drawCircle(0, 0, 50);
  circle.x = 100;
  circle.y = 100;
  stage.addChild(circle);
  stage.update();

 }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to import the createjs code. Something like `import { createjs } from 'where ever the createjs code is';`

Comment: I tried using `import { createjs } from 'createjs';` but that just led to a compiler error saying "Cannot find module 'node_modules/createjs'." I am assuming this error is happening because the createjs folder is just javascript files, no modules.

Comment: Take a look at this then: https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-libraries-in-angular-2-apps-ff274ba601af

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @types for createjs seem to be formatted as a namespace instead of a module. If you import as below:

```
import 'createjs';
```

You can then access for example:

```
createjs.Stage
```

Comment: Just tried that and recieved an error saying "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'createjs' in [typescript file path]"

Comment: is reference path added?

Comment: Yes, /// <reference types="@types/createjs" /> is the first line in the code.